# How often does evacuation happen as shown during the pre-flight safety videos/stewardess instructions?

Tags: safety, airliner, evacuation

I believe it is mandatory for airlines to provide passengers with information about evacuation in case of emergencies. However, pretty much every accident I've ever heard off either happens at the airport (where normal exit routes are available) or in the middle of nowhere (where no passenger makes it out alive).

Is there any statistics on how often do "normal" evacuations happen among Western airlines? The only example I can think off is the Hudson landing of [US Airways Flight 1549](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Airways_Flight_1549).

Comment: You're right that the vast majority of evacuations happen at airports, but that doesn't mean they're using the 'normal exit routes'. I don't have any hard data for you, but head over to [AvHerald](http://avherald.com) and search for ["evacuation via slides"](http://avherald.com/h?search_term=evacuation+via+slides&dosearch=1).

Comment: That's a great link! Thanks

Comment: I would imagine that the evacuation happens more often in the filming of evacuation scenes than it does in real life... but I have absolutely nothing to back that up with.

Comment: @mah: I don't think so. Precautionary evacuation is quite common.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't do statistics, but [The Aviation Herald](http://avherald.com/) lists units to low tens a year worldwide.

Most of them happen at airport due to fire indication (sometimes even false) or smoke on board.

On the ground, fire spreads a lot faster than while flying, because when flying, the wind is too strong and blowing the flames off. The most notable example would be [China Airlines B738 at Okinawa on Aug. 20th 2007, airplane in flames arriving at stand](http://avherald.com/h?article=3f8fb20e). The aircraft was already at the gate when the flames were first noticed, evacuation was immediately initiated and by the time everybody left, it was already engulfed in flames, about 3 minutes after the fire started. While China Air might not be "western" in strict sense of the world, it is largest airline on Taiwan and follows the same standards.

Another notable accident is [Egyptair B772 at Cairo on Jul 29th 2011, cockpit fire](http://avherald.com/h?article=44078aa7).

Here are some recent evacuations mentioned on AvHerald:

- [Air France B773 at Paris on Jul 28th 2013, evacuation while boarding due to fumes](http://avherald.com/h?article=46691d37)
- [US Airways B752 at Kona on Jun 8th 2013, evacuation during push back causes 4 injuries](http://avherald.com/h?article=46406feb)
- [PSA CRJ2 near Philadelphia on Apr 17th 2013, smoke on board, evacuation](http://avherald.com/h?article=460e76eb)
- [Easyjet A319 at Belfast on Jan 6th 2011, taxiway de-icing prompts evacuation](http://avherald.com/h?article=44fe403b)

Notice, that they are all smoke or fire events. For some other reasons, see e.g.:

- [Wizz A320 at Rome on Jun 8th 2013, left main gear did not extend](http://avherald.com/h?article=46380ff0)
- [Alitalia A320 at Rome on Sep 29th 2013, right main gear did not extend](http://avherald.com/h?article=469338e0)

two similar accidents where both aircraft were evacuated via slides. The reason in these, and many other gear collapse incidents, is that they don't want to wait in a damaged plane where there is a *risk* of fire, plus the difficulty of getting stairs to the aircraft resting in strange attitude.